# Перевод из с++ в си

Tags: c++, c

```
    #include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
 int n; 
 cin » n; 
 double s = 0; 
 for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
 s += double(i+1)/double(i); 
 cout « s; 
 system("pause"); 
 return 0
```

;
}

Answer (score 1):

Перевел, если можно так сказать на си. Написал код без библиотеки iostream, которая как раз относится к c++

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double s = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        s += ((double)(i + 1)) / i;
    printf("%f", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1 и 3 строки не нужны. Ну и `system("pause");`

Comment: Насколько я помню Си (!), в нем нет функции `double()`. Правильно написать c приведением типа (*cast*) вот так `s += ((double)(i + 1)) / i;`  (в данном случае делитель `i` преобразуется к типу double автоматически)